# Событие window.onload в iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Мне нужно проверить что в iframe загрузился dom вместе с ресурсами (картинками) на нем. Хотел использовать window.onload внутри iframe, но почему-то это событие не отрабатывает. DOMContentLoaded - работает нормально.
Можно ли внутри iframe вообще использовать window.onload и если нет, то как проверить что ресурсы загрузились?

Comment: Родитель и фрейм находятся на одном домене?

Comment: Нет. Я не корректно сформулировал вопрос.
Я передаю в iframe разметку через postMessage и там ее рендерю.
В разметку есть обработчик onload вот он не работает.

Comment: Те вы хотите что то отрендерить внутри фрейма когда он полностью загрузился?

Comment: Да. Событие DOMContentLoaded отрабатывает, а вот c onload беда

Answer (score 0):

При запуске window.onload внутри фрейма, вы не получите доступ к этому событию из родителя. Но вы же можете проверить когда именно загрузился ваш фрейм.

Пример: `<iframe src="url фрейма" id="pageFrame"></iframe>`

Получаем событие:

```
window.pageFrame.onload = function(){
  alert('Фрейм готов получать postMessage');
}
```

PS я делал немного не так делал, в фрейме проверял window.onload, когда он загрузился, отправляю postMessage на родителя, родитель приняв параметры, отправляет в фрейм нужные параметры